# Ansible vault passwords appears in log if task fails

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I am using ansible vault to store my passwords , Its working wonderfully.
Issue I have is when any task fails it shows those passwords in logs.
How Can I hide these passwords in all the situations?

This is my sample task

```
- name: Run python script for generating Projects report
  command: python GetProjects.py -o { org1 } -p { pat1 }
  register: result
- debug: msg="{{result.stdout}}"
```

If task fails It shows my pat and org in logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide the output, you can use the [`no_log`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html) option:

```yaml
- name: Run python script for generating Projects report
  command: python GetProjects.py -o { org1 } -p { pat1 }
  register: result
  no_log: true
```